# Setting consistency rules to monotonic for a session with the official Mongo Go driver mongo-go-driver (session.SetMode in mgo)

Tags: mongodb, go

We're switching to the official driver, away from the deprecated mgov2

In mgo we set the session mode to be monotonic like this:

```
myMongoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
```

My understanding of doing so is to ensure: "If a process reads the value of a data item x, any successive read operation on x by that process will always return that same value or a more recent value."

This is important for us

How would I do this using the official driver? I can't find a reference to doing so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding of doing so is to ensure: "If a process reads the value of a data item x, any successive read operation on x by that process will always return that same value or a more recent value."

Yes, but not always. Let's look into the code comment for Monotonic mode [session.go#L73](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/blob/master/session.go#L73):

```
// Monotonic mode is specific to mgo, and is same as SecondaryPreferred before first write. 
// Same as Primary after first write.
Monotonic Mode = 1
```

According to [godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Session.SetMode) for `SetMode()`:

> In the Monotonic consistency mode reads may not be entirely
>   up-to-date, but they will always see the history of changes moving
>   forward, the data read will be consistent across sequential queries in
>   the same session, and modifications made within the session will be
>   observed in following queries (read-your-writes).
>
> In practice, the Monotonic mode is obtained by performing initial
>   reads on a unique connection to an arbitrary secondary, if one is
>   available, and once the first write happens, the session connection is
>   switched over to the primary server. This manages to distribute some
>   of the reading load with secondaries, while maintaining some useful
>   guarantees.

For most of the cases this is true, however there could be instances where `SecondaryPreferred` may choose *different* secondaries that could have different [Oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) times.

> How would I do this using the official driver?

Monotonic mode is a term specific for mgo, and does not exist for [MongoDB Go driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo). This has been superseded by new features such as [causal consistency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#causal-consistency) and/or [multi-document transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/).

`mongo-go-driver` is more verbose, but also to provide more control over [read preferences](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/), [read concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/), and [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/)

Example of causal consistency:

```
opts := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI).SetReadPreference(readpref.Secondary()).SetReadConcern(readconcern.Majority()).SetWriteConcern(writeconcern.New(writeconcern.WMajority()))
client, err := mongo.NewClient(opts)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

For transactions example see [Transactions in Applications](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-in-applications) (Choose `Go` language on the tab)